# How to create a new user in MariaDB in one command line in Debian

Tags: mysql, linux, terminal, debian, mariadb

I want to create a new database access user, but I need to pass the entire command on the same line:

```
mysql -u root; CREATE USER 'test' @ '%' IDENTIFIED BY '123456'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *. * TO 'test' @ '%'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [echo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) command like:

```
echo "CREATE USER 'test' @ '%' IDENTIFIED BY '123456'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *. * TO 'test' @ '%'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; " | mysql -u root
```

Or use the `-e` option:

```
mysql -u root -e "CREATE USER 'test' @ '%' IDENTIFIED BY '123456'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *. * TO 'test' @ '%'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```